# Show dropdown when option is selected in the another dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have one main dropdown, when one of the option is selected in the dropdown, in the next text field another dropdown has to come with different values, and when other option is selected in the main dropdown in the text has to appear in the same text field. So basically my question is, how to add both text and dropdwon in the same input field when the option is selected in the dropdown.

I have tried to do the one part of the problem i.e , when first two option is selected the value is appearing in input field , but I'm not able to make the dropdown appear in the input field when third option is selected.

Can anyone help me on this problem!

```html
<html>

<body>
  <label> Assets:</label>
  <select id="name" onchange="func()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="year">Calendar</option>
    <option value="the current month">Month</option>
    <option id="no-of-days">Days</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <label>Days:</label>
  <input type="text" id="days">

  <script>
    function func() {

      var dropdown = document.getElementById("name");
      var selection = dropdown.value;
      console.log(selection);
      var TextBox = document.getElementById("days");
      TextBox.value = selection;

      document.getElementById('no-of-days').onclick = function() {

        var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

        var select = document.createElement("select");
        select.name = "date";
        select.id = "date"

        for (const val of values) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = val;
          option.text = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
          select.appendChild(option);
        }
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.innerHTML = "Choose your date: "
        label.htmlFor = "date";

        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(label).appendChild(select);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry i cannot Test it yet because I have to leave in 3minutes. But I don’t think you will get a click event on the option element. Why don’t you use a change event on the select and add the new select if it changed to the 3 value?

Comment: If your question is to trigger based on selecting third option from the dropdown, then you have to call `.change()` on dropdown and run the function `if ($(this).val() == 'option3')`.  If you are asking about using one element for for both text and dropdown then try `<details>`. CHeck this link (https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_datalist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not selecting the days `dropdown` as you should be. There is no `value` for days option (third option).

1. Firstly we need to set the value of third option
2. Check if its selected select `onchange` function

We can the check on `change` if the `value` of *selected* `option` is `no-of-days` then we can append another `dropdown` OR `else` we will *not* show anything.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
function func() {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("name");
  var selection = dropdown.value;
  var TextBox = document.getElementById("days");
  var appendNewSelect = document.getElementById("container")
  TextBox.value = selection;

  //If days (option) is selected
  if (selection == 'no-of-days') {

    var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

    //Create Select
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.name = "date";
    select.id = "date"

    //Select option
    for (const val of values) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = val;
      option.text = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
      select.appendChild(option);
    }

    //Label
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.innerHTML = "Choose your date: "
    label.htmlFor = "date";
    
    appendNewSelect.appendChild(label).appendChild(select);
  } else {
    appendNewSelect.innerHTML = ''
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <label> Assets:</label>
  <select id="name" onchange="func()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="year">Calendar</option>
    <option value="the current month">Month</option>
    <option value="no-of-days">Days</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <label>Days:</label>
  <input type="text" id="days">
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="container">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @SushmaA You are welcome. Would you mind accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please. Mark as the solution